# efficient frontiers are equal

Tags: portfolio-optimization, risk, sharpe-ratio

I created 3 different efficient frontiers with 3 different risk factors(sharpe ratio, ulcer performance index and serenity ratio) and I wanted to find both MSR and GMV(and their equivalent for the other two risk factors) on each one. But all 6 points are the exact same point. I wanted to know if it has a meaning behind it. Does anyone know what it means? (Rf=0)

Comment: How do you calculate this? You have historical returns on N securities for T periods? And then how do you calculate the frontiers? What is on the 2 axes when you plot the frontiers? I can't quite follow what you are doing. I would think the results would be different.

Comment: yes I have 30 securities on a time period. the Y axis is r and the x axis is the denominator of the risk factor(for example for sharpe its SD). and I randomly generate 2000 portfolios and draw the Efficient frontier based on those

Answer (score 0):

If you use the same dataset across all three portfolios you will find the same efficient combination across all three. Ergo, your sharpe ratio will be the same, because it basically uses the same tools. Instead, the allocation should be different in cases where you are going to minimize the ulcer index etc.